# Cloud9 deploy hitting size limit for numpy, pandas

Tags: pandas, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I'm building in Cloud9 to deploy to Lambda.  My function works fine in Cloud9 but when I go to deploy I get the error

> Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

Running `du -h | sort -h` shows that my biggest offenders are:

- `/debug` at 291M
- `/numpy` at 79M
- `/pandas` at 47M
- `/botocore` at 41M

My function is extremely simple, it calls a service, uses panda to format the response, and sends it on.

1. What is in debug and how do I slim it down/eliminate it from the deploy package?
2. How do others use libraries at all if they eat up most of the memory limit?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue importing pandas and bokeh, which takes up almost all of the size allocation for a Lambda function. I'm building from "clean" on a CI server, so I shouldn't have created extraneous temporary files. Upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A brief background to understand the problem root-cause**

The problem is not with your function but with the size of the zipped packages. As per AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html), the overall size of zipped package must not exceed greater than 3MB. With that said, if the package size is greater than 3MB which happens inevitably, as a library can have many dependencies, then consider uploading the zipped package to a `AWS S3 bucket`. Note: even s3 bucket has a size limit of `262MB`. Ensure that your package does not exceed this limit. The error message that you have posted, `Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes` is referring to the size of the deployment package aka the libraries.

Now, Understand some facts when working with AWS,

1. *AWS Containers are empty*.
2. *AWS containers have a linux kernel*
3. AWS Cloud9 is only an IDE like RStudio or Pycharm. And it uses S3 bucket for saving the installed packages.

This means you'll need to know the following:

1. the package and its related dependencies
2. extract the linux-compiled packages from cloud9 and save to a folder-structure like, `python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

**Possible/Workable solution to overcome this problem**

Overcome this problem by reducing the package size. See below.

**Reducing the deployment package size**

- Manual method: delete files and folders within each library folder that are named `*.info` and `*._pycache`. You'll need to manually look into each folder for the above file extensions to delete them.
- Automatic method: I've to figure out the command. work in progress

**Use Layers**

In AWS go to Lambda and create a layer

Attach the S3 bucket link containing the python package folder. Ensure the lambda function IAM role has permission to access S3 bucket.

Make sure the un-zipped folder size is less than 262MB. Because if its >260 MB then it cannot be attached to AWS Layer. You'll get an error, `Failed to create layer version: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes`